# compute gc content for specific ID

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a dictionary called self.__sequences reads like "ID:DNA sequence", and the following is part of that dictionary

```
{
 '1111758': ('TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAA\n', ''), 
 '1111762': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGA\n', ''),
 '1111763': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCCTT\n', '')
}
```

I want to compute the gc conent for a specific sequence ID (some_id). That is, If some_id is in the dictionary, return the gc content of the DNA sequence for that ID; if some_id does not exist,return an error message

P.S. gc content= (G+C)/(A+T+G+C) for a DNA sequence

I write the following code (the function is under class) but it gives me error message. I appreciate if anyone can help me to improve my code

```
def compute_gc_content(self, some_id=''):
    """compute the gc conent for sequence ID (some_id). If some_id is in the  
dictionary, return the gc content of the DNA sequence for that ID; if some_id 
does not exist,return an error message"""

self.some_id = some_id
    for i in range(len(self.__sequences)):
    if self.some_id in self.__sequences.keys():
        return (self.some_id.values['G']+self.some_id.values['C'])/float(len(self.__sequences))
    else:
        return "This ID does not exist"
```

so if I print compute_gc_content('1111758'), i want to print the value of gc content, such as 0.23.

Comment: i make up the number. Just want to illustrate what I want

Comment: Do you mean gc content = (Count(G) + Count(C)) / (Count(A) + Count(T) + Count(G) + Count(C)) ?

Comment: And what error message do you get?

Comment: If you copy pasted that code then your identatino is wrong, maybe the error message is about that?

Comment: yes. I mean (Count(G) + Count(C)) / (Count(A) + Count(T) + Count(G) + Count(C)) , i think I am not sure how to count the number of "C"s and "G"s in a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly.

```
def compute_gc_content(self, some_id=''):

    if some_id in self.__sequences:
        seq = self.__sequences['some_id'][0]
        return (seq.count('G')+seq.count('C'))/float(len(seq))
    else:
        return "This ID does not exist"
```

No need to use `in self.__sequences.keys()`, `in self.__sequences` does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the error message when ID does not exist, however, I always get 0.0 if I input an existing ID. Why is that?

Comment: Thank you. Your code was correct. Can you please explain what does

Comment: Thank you. Your code was correct. Can you please explain what does    self.__sequences['some_id'][0] mean, especially the [0]? thank you

Comment: @neymar You see, your data is in such form `('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGA\n', '')`, which is a 2-elements tuple. [0] means the first element, which is your DNA seq.

Comment: I do not understand self.__sequences['some_id'][0]

Comment: @neymar see http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range

Comment: i understand that self.__sequences['some_id'] will return the value for some_id, but i am confused about I do not understand self.__sequences['some_id'][0], what does [0] do? Thank you

Comment: @neymar Glad you got it resolved. please accept if you don'y have other questions :)

Comment: how can i choose your answer as the best one? I really wanna give you some reputation because I learn a lot useful from you.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
import itertools

class gc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__sequences = {'1111758': ('TTAGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAA\n', ''), '1111762': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGATTGA\n', ''), '1111763': ('AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCCTT\n', '')}


def compute_gc_content(self, some_id=''):
    """compute the gc conent for sequence ID (some_id). If some_id is in the  
    dictionary, return the gc content of the DNA sequence for that ID; if some_id 
    does not exist,return an error message"""

    self.some_id = some_id
    for i in range(len(self.__sequences)):
        if self.some_id in self.__sequences.keys():
            return (float)(self.__sequences[some_id][0].count('G')+self.__sequences[some_id][0].count('C'))/(len(self.__sequences[some_id][0]))
        else:
            return "This ID does not exist"

print gc().compute_gc_content('1111758')
```